# Remove from string

Tags: php

I have the following that I need removed from string in loop.

```
<comment>Some comment here</comment>
```

The result is from a database so the the content inside the comment tag is different.
Thanks for the help.

Figured it out. The following seems to do the trick.

`echo preg_replace('~\<comment>.*?\</comment>~', '', $blog->comment);`

Comment: So you want to remove the `<comment>` tags?  Are there any other HTML tags in this string?

Comment: Do you want to remove the text inside the tags too?

Comment: Seems like XML to me, so `DOM` & `getELementsByTagName` should work pretty much out of the box...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I would like to remove both the <comment> and the text inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be overkill, but you can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the string as HTML, then remove the tags.

```
$str = 'Test 123 <comment>Some comment here</comment> abc 456';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
// Wrap $str in a div, so we can easily extract the HTML from the DOMDocument
@$dom->loadHTML("<div id='string'>$str</div>");  // It yells about <comment> not being valid
$comments = $dom->getElementsByTagName('comment');
foreach($comments as $c){
   $c->parentNode->removeChild($c);
}
$domXPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// $dom->getElementById requires the HTML be valid, and it's not here
// $dom->saveHTML() adds a DOCTYPE and HTML tag, which we don't need
echo $domXPath->query('//div[@id="string"]')->item(0)->nodeValue; // "Test 123  abc 456"
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/wfzsmpAW

Answer (score 1):

If this is *only* a matter of removing the `<comment />` tag, a simple `preg_replace()` or a `str_replace()` will do:

```
$input = "<comment>Some comment here</comment>";

// Probably the best method str_replace()
echo str_replace(array("<comment>","</comment>"), "", $input);
// some comment here

// Or by regular expression...    
echo preg_replace("/<\/?comment>/", "", $input);
// some comment here
```

Or if there are other tags in there and you want to strip out all but a few, use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) with its optional second parameter to specify allowable tags.

```
echo strip_tags($input, "<a><p><other_allowed_tag>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to remove the comment tags and also the text inside.